# SQL Server - compound statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a project in C#, and am executing this statement, but not getting back anything (using a datatable to get data back)

```
string SQL = 
  "DECLARE @NewID int; SELECT TOP 1 @NewID = [ItemID] + 1 FROM [GroupItems] ORDER BY [ItemID] DESC; " + 
  "INSERT INTO [GroupItems] ([InstanceID], [ItemID], [GroupID], [ItemName], [DisplayName], [Units], [Updated]) " +
  "VALUES(@instanceID, @NewID, @groupID, @name, @display, @units, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); SELECT * FROM [GroupItems] WHERE [ItemID]=@NewID";
```

Basically what I want to do is return the row I just created. Any help?

Comment: Is this query works fine in SQL Management Studio Express ?

Comment: Perhaps add the code that executes the query?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the group items table?   If you change the last line to SELECT 1, do you get a 1 back....

Comment: @Sudantha:  The query works in the query manager

Comment: OK, now try SELECT TOP 1 * FROM groupItems.   This will indicate if the WHERE clause is the issue, or something else

Answer (score 2):

- You are probably missing information because of the @variables being NULL. How do you set them?
- Are suppressing errors somehow.
- Do you get data stored in the table, or just no results?

Anyway, there are easier ways to do this in one line

First off, make the ItemID column an IDENTITY. Otherwise this code *will* fail at some point because it isn't safe for overlappping calls

Then second, change the code to use the OUTPUT clause. You can do this in one go

```
INSERT INTO [GroupItems] ([InstanceID], [GroupID], [ItemName], [DisplayName], [Units], [Updated])
OUTOUT INSERTED.*
VALUES(@instanceID, @groupID, @name, @display, @units, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```